# Any rails code inside haml tags generates blank/empty characters inside browsers html tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css, haml

Whenever a rails variable equals nil (or actually whenever i use rails code (see 3rd code sample)) i get a string of empty characters in my html.

*new.html.haml*

```
%h1.editable.editable_title_field{:contenteditable => 'true', :placeholder => "title"}
  = @post_title //@post_title.present? returns false
%h4.editable.editable_subtitle_field{:contenteditable => 'true', :placeholder => "subtitle"}
  = @post.subtitle
%p.editable.editable_intro_field{:contenteditable => 'true', :placeholder => "intro"}
  = @post.intro
```

this results in:

[image]

i checked, and even:

```
%h1.editable.editable_title_field{:contenteditable => 'true', :placeholder => "title"}
  - @post_title
```

and:

```
%h1.editable.editable_title_field{:contenteditable => 'true', :placeholder => "title"}
  -
```

ends up the same as in attached image

because of those empty characters `:empty` css selector treats the element as if it was not empty and doesnt append content specified in `:before`

how do i get rid of those empty characters inside my html tags?

**EDIT**

screencast of this behavior:
http://quick.as/jqlaiorq

Comment: I'm removing my answer. This is strange. I can't recreate the behaviour here.

Comment: as you suggested this propably is related to haml :/

Comment: you said `@post_title.present?` returns false, wouldn't that mean it's nil and it's generating an empty string ?

Comment: Maybe `= @post_title.strip`? Also, should it be `%h1`? (I don't use haml)

Comment: i tried that, undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass :)

Comment: i added a screencast explanining how it looks like exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a `<` on the end of the `%h1` line:

```
%h1.editable.editable_title_field{:contenteditable => 'true', :placeholder => "title"}<
  = @post_title
```

See the [whitespace removal info](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_) in the HAML documentation.

Comment: indeed, those alligators ate all the whitespace! :) thank you!